# Getting group feeds via Facebook Graph API returns limited result list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get feeds from public Facebook groups via Facebook Graph API. The documentation says, that I need "Any valid access token if the group is public" to get the news feed from public groups.

I am trying to call this request with valid access token:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=vyvojari%2Ffeed&version=v2.8
```

but I only get few old posts instead of the list of actual posts.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what is not a group, it´s a page...and i get the latest entries without any problem

Comment: First of all, that’s a page, not a group. Secondly, the latest post I see on that page on Facebook is from August 9, 2016 - and that is also the first one I see returned in Graph API Explorer.